# How to conditionally shrink one view or grow a different view depending on screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to layout an activity with two views inside of it as shown below.

Blue View: This view is always square. It's max height is whatever the width of the window is. When needed, it can shrink, but will always stay square.

Green View: This view has a minimum height, but no maximum. If the containing window is really tall, the height of this view will grow.

[image]

Does anything one know to handle this in android's xml layout? I've tried with layout_weights, but haven't been able to get it to work both ways (shrinking & growing).

The surrounding ViewGroup is a LinearLayout if that helps.

Comment: you said width of blue square is always same as screen width but in last image I see you dont have full width..

Comment: There is no easy way to achieve what you are trying to do with XML layout because there are 2 conditions which can not be satisfied at the same time in XML. 1: mint height, 2 square. So my take is you can do it in the code by using conditions based on screen size, First of all, subtract min height form screen height and compare if remaining height is more than width then make width and height of blue view equals to width and increase the height of green view else keep the height of green view equals to min height and make the width and height of blue view equals to remaining height.

Comment: That's too bad, I was hoping I wouldn't have to do it programatically. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> First get the value of you screen width in terms of dp

```html
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

> Then set the same value of display width in dp to the height of the layout

```html
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpHeight, dpHeight);
```

> You will always have squire layout irrespective of device screen
>
> And this is the way to achieve minimum height of a layout

```html
SmartImageView siv = new SmartImageView(getActivity());
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, minHeight);
siv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I received, I ended up doing the following (slightly customized for my solution, but including the code in case it helps anyone else).

In the layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/blueWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/blueSquare"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/blueSquare"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/blueSquare"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/blueSquare"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/blueSquare"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"/>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <!--EXTRA ELEMENTS HERE-->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- 100dp is the minHeight -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/greenWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" 
            android:background="@color/green" >

            <!--ELEMENTS HERE-->

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity);

    // Other initialization stuff here

    final LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    final RelativeLayout blueWrapper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.blueWrapper);
    final View blueSquare = (View) findViewById(R.id.blueSquare);
    final RelativeLayout greenWrapper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.greenWrapper);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = root.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            root.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            int rootHeight = root.getHeight();

            if(blueWrapper.getHeight() > blueWrapper.getWidth()){
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = greenWrapper.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = rootHeight - blueSquare.getWidth();
                greenWrapper.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The logic behind this is:

- On load, everything will work as expected unless it's the tall window case.
- For the tall window case, the blue will stretch to have a greater height than width, making it easy to identify.
- When that happens, just calculate the difference between blueHeight & blueWidth & add that to the original height of the green wrapper.